# Just a part of TOC must be shown, beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, table-of-contents

Before I start talking about a new section, I would like to show de TOC whereby the part (section) that I will talk about is shown? So I would like that the rest is only vague opposite the section I will talk about.
Can somebody help me?

Silke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\AtBeginSection` to include a `\tableofcontents`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[] % Do nothing for \section*
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline - Section \thesection}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document} 

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Three}
\begin{frame} test \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the outline for the first section:

[image]

An image of the outline for the second section:

[image]

Refer to Section **10.5 Adding a Table of Contents** for the multiple options you can use for `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: @Silke you're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer (by clisking in the checkmark to its left), if you consider it solved your problem. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: I've just got only one question.. I'm from Belgium, so I would like to have everything in Dutch. I've used \usepackage[dutch]{babel} but when I use your code that doesn't work anymore.. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Silke just adding the line `\usepackage[dutch]{babel}` to my example code doesn't produce any problems, so there must be something else going on in your document. Reduce your code to a minimal, complete document producing the problem, and open a fresh new question, including the minimal document.